# Как убрать title bar в tkinter?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, mac

Многие програмы при загрузке создают окно без title bar'а.
Kак это сделать в Ткинтере.
Нe

```
 root.overrideredirect(1)
```

Oн просто дизактивиpyeт кнопки закрытия,cворачивания и разворачивания ,а мне надо полностью убрать title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.X на Windows:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

Python 3.X на macOS:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-type', 'dock')
root.geometry('1600x800')
tk.Entry(root).pack()
root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У меня почему то :
tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-type": must be -alpha, -fullscreen, -modified, -notify, -titlepath, -topmost, or -transparent

Comment: @Victor поправил, попробуйте у себя.

Comment: Все равно:_tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-type": must be -alpha, -fullscreen, -modified, -notify, -titlepath, -topmost, or -transparent

Comment: @Victor, как я вам уже писал в другом вопрсое, tkinter имеет плохою клосплатформенность. По мимо этого tkinter имеет крайне плохую документацию, которая не позволяет мне должным образом ответить на ваш вопрос. Я бы рекомендовал вам присмотреться к Qt

Comment: Вообще сейчас я вообще используюсь  kivy.А про tkinter я спрашивал, потому что import kivy и nltk занимают некоторое время и я хочу пустить заставочку (tkinter быстрый ) .Спасибо за такие быстрые ответы.Qt и так использую — вещь!
Поиспользую  для заставки само kivy.